# C# How can I export a ListView to .CSV in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, csv

How can I export a ListView (populated with sqlite) to .CSV in WPF? i can do it on winforms but not in wpf.. pls help. thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: How do you do it in WinForms and why doesn't the same approach work in WPF?

Comment: As Mentioned before, there shouldn't be a big difference like you do it in console or winform applications. iterate through your entities / datarows and write it. Perhaps provice some example code how your datalooks like and point out where you are stuck

Comment: here look at this image were im stuck in wpf:|>>>>

[stuck in wpf](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJL5z.jpg)

Comment: I would change the approach. When loading data store it in a custom property. Then when exporting it use this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert ListView to Datatable:

```
var listView1 = new ListView();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    table.Columns.Add(item.ToString());
    foreach (var it in item.SubItems)
         table.Rows.Add(it.ToString());
 }
```

Use following code to make a csv:

```
public void CreateCSVFile(DataTable dt, string strFilePath)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);

    int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
    {
        sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
        if (i < iColCount - 1)
        {
            sw.Write(",");
        }
    }
    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
            {
                sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
            }
            if (i < iColCount - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: I've i treid it but it's not working on me.. i still got red squiggly line on the part of Columns.. did i missing something? >>>>> 
  
[Image Error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QmLps.jpg)

Comment: In WPF the ListView doesn't have the Columns property. Maybe first convert your ListView to a DataTable and work from there ...

Comment: changed the code to convert listview to datatable and go from there ...

Comment: I tried it already thanks man.. but i got error on converting ListView to Datatable is their other way do it?... thanks

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: on convert ListView to Datatable inside of the foreach( the foreach (var it in item.SubItems)) SubItems is not supported.

Comment: Can you get items from the listview like this: ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)listView.Items[0];